# Store Customer data when app is downloaded from google play

Tags: android

I have created an android App. In which i want too things.

1) At the time of installing application, Customer should register with his name, email and phone number. and That information i want to store..

So how can we store that Registration information

2)Is there any way to copy contacts(After seeking permission) of the phone while installing android app

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google provides a software hook to allow you to do that when the app is installed.  A more standard way to accomplish that would be to detect a first time start up of the app and then collect the information .

Comment: Thanks for you comment.. Can we can save that data to our remote database..? how..?

Comment: Yes. One way would be to use HTTP(S) to invoke a server side PHP script passing it the data.  The PHP script can then update your database.